# Replace twitter feed by blog entries

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

In the default [mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) theme, on the right hand side there is a [twitter feed](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/packages.html#module-mezzanine.twitter). I would like to replace this with the latest blog entries.  I believe that `{% blog_recent_posts 5 as recent_posts %}` as [documented here](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/packages.html#module-mezzanine.blog) should do the trick but I cannot find where I need to add this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the time to look at the "templates" directory in each of the apps (core, blog, galleries, etc).

These will show you all the default templates, which you can override by creating with the same paths as in those apps, but in a "templates" directory in your own project.

You'll see in mezzanine/core/templates there's a base.html - that's the root template that all others extend, so you'll generally want to copy that into your project's templates folder.

Within base.html you'll see where the tweets get included, so you can start customising things from there.

If you have any other questions, you'll get a much quicker response on the mailing list.

Comment: Super, that's what I needed.  Many thanks.  Sure, mailing list might have been faster but that way it gives visibility to mezzanine which it deserves.